# Make Navagation menu change color when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, web-deployment

I am having issues making my WordPress Nav Menu change color when I scroll down. Right now it is transparent and I would like it to change to white when a visitor scrolls downwards. I tried a few custom CSS and Javascript codes I found on here but none of them work. Here is my website, can someone take a look, please.
https://seoitservice.com/

Comment: you need to add some jquery script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove This script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var scroll_start=0;
        var startchange=$('#startchange');
        var offset=startchange.offset();
        if(startchange.length){
            $(document).scroll(function(){
                scroll_start=$(this).scrollTop();
                if(scroll_start>offset.top){
                    $(".navbar-default").css('background-color','#f0f0f0');
                }else{
                    $('.navbar-default').css('background-color','transparent');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

and this script and style above `</head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 500) {       
            jQuery(".main-header-bar-wrap").addClass("fixedHeader");
        }else{
            jQuery(".main-header-bar-wrap").removeClass("fixedHeader");
        }
    }); 
</script> 

<style>
.main-header-bar-wrap.fixedHeader{
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It workedddddddddd Thank you soo muchhhhhhhhhh. I have been trying for ever to get it to work! thanks alotttttttttt

Comment: Thanks. Glad to help you